# Interesting case of shadowing parameter C++ (parameter not shadowed in an if block)

Tags: c++, gcc, shadowing

I surprising discovered today that the following code is completely valid (gcc 4.4.5):

```
int get_int(const int& i)
{
    if(i == 0)
    {
        int i = 1;
        return i;
    }
    return i;       
}
```

I am really surprised. If I have to accept it, then sure I can say that it sort of makes sense because the new variable is within its own block, so the rest of the code outside can still access the parameter, so the parameter is not really shadowed. But it still doesn't make sense to me why did we NOT make this an invalid syntax? I see no benefits of allowing this, and in fact, I just had to dig into a bug caused by this. It was a long function and I created my own variable without realizing it has the same name as a parameter, and some lines of code later(same block) there is a dependence on that very parameter variable, and boom now it is using my version and there goes an hour of my day.

I have very surface knowledge about compilers, so could somebody explain to me the full story behind this behavior? As a comparison, in Java code like this is invalid (duplicate variable).

Comment: Not an expert in compilers either but I would suspect the fact that the argument is an int& and the "shadowing" variable only an int to be in the loop here.

Comment: I also tried `get_int(int i)` it makes no difference

Comment: The scope of the `int i` is the block in which it is declared. This shadows the parameter inside the block, but not outside it. If you're asking "Why is a variable scoped to the block instead of the function?" the answer is "That's what the language rules say." Different languages follow different rules. That's what makes them different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking why C++ allows this, the answer is simple: In order to accept valid C code.

It also makes the rules simpler, to handle different meanings for the same identifier in different scopes all the same way, without caring whether the scopes involved are namespaces, classes, functions, or block scopes.

Comment: mind explaining a bit more? could you illustrate how this has anything to do with accepting valid C code?

Comment: C++'s popularity when it was introduced depended on the fact that pretty much all good C code was acceptable under the C++ rules.

Answer (score -4):

You are not passing a variable but a reference. Quoting Bjarne Stroustroup in ***the C++ Programming Language*** - "A reference can be used to implement a function that is supposed to change the value of its argument" p.62

Comment: This misses the point of the question, which is "Why am I allowed to partially shadow a parameter?"

Comment: you didn't get the question.. sorry I didn't put it in a clearer way. Also I passed in a const reference so it wouldn't make a difference anyways